# Open new Activity from Xamarin Custom Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, custom-renderer

This is my first Custom Renderer project and just getting hold of xamarin. I have a Camera Custom Renderer, and want to pass the image preview (through the file path) to another activity for extra functions, in Android.
Using the classic:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ResultPage));
        StartActivity(intent);
```

It throws to errors: 
-The first one in "this", says that "error CS1503 argument 1: 'CustomRenderer.Droid.CameraPageRenderer' canto be converted to 'Android.Content.Context'"
-Second, is in "StartActivity" that says "Error CS0103  The name 'StartActivity' doesn't exist in the actual context 'CustomRenderer.Android'"

Here's is the method where it should go:

```
        async void TakePhotoButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        camera.StopPreview();

        var image = textureView.Bitmap;

        try
        {
            var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
            var folderPath = absolutePath + "/Images";
            var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("image_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

            var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();

            image.Recycle();

            var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            intent.SetData(uri);
            MainActivity.Instance.SendBroadcast(intent);

            CameraPageRenderer cameraPageRenderer = this;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ResultPage));
            StartActivity(intent);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"               ", ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CustomRenderer` is not an Android `Context`. You need to retrieve the current Android `Context` and use it:

```
var context = this.Context;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(ResultPage));
context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Remember that your custom renderer needs to implement the parameterized constructor that accepts a Context as it's parameter in order for this to work:

```
public MyCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }
```

Comment: THANKS!!! I wish I could upvote you. Wherever you are, feel my hug and scream of happiness when it worked. I hope you have an incredible life.<3

Comment: @NatanOrtegaWhite glad it worked. remember to accept the answer if it was correct.